# Focus in Bookmarks Sidebar

Tags: safari, shortcut, bookmarks, sidebar

I cannot seem to get focus to set into the Bookmarks Sidebar.

None of the following shortcuts accomplish this:

- <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>-<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> Toggle Sidebar
- <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> Toggle Sidebar w/ Bookmarks opened
- <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> Open Bookmarks page

I've experimented with <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>tab ⇥</kbd> but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How do you envisage focussing? The Bookmark sidebar items can't be clicked on without actioning them. You can't just select one as though it was a file in Finder.

Comment: @Tetsujin They way I achieve this in Notes, to get to the "folders sidebar", is by ⌥-⌘-F to title bar search (as opposed to ⌘-F note search), then single tab into folder area so that I can select another folder quickly. I'd like to do the same to at least select existing pages for now, although more shortcuts for adding new folders whilst in this view would be useful (not sure yet if there is a general shortcut for "right-click" / "option-click" / "double-tap" in macOS, Windows has a few and even a dedicated key)

Comment: @Tetsujin Just being able to get focus into the search box of the Bookmarks Sidebar would be helpful, even though the keyboard can't be used to navigate out of it for some reason